# How to pass current date to a text field using Angular JS in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I have a field to add date which is of type text.It has the following HTML code

```
<input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" type="text" id="date" name="date">
```

Could someone help me to send current date to the field.I tried many ways,but when I am using Date() to get current date,it is not even executing the test

Comment: can you add the code for the test that isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I almost got it.I am now using

```
 this.dateField.sendKeys(d.getMonth() + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear());
```

It is returning date as 11/11/2017.That means except month all others are working.The format is MM/DD/YYYY.

Comment: getMonth() returns from 0-11.So we have to give getMonth() +1.

Comment: So the final code is _` this.datetField.sendKeys((d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear());`_

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work just fine for me. I just used the google search page to check it. I put a 10 second sleep in so I can visually check it was working.

```
it('should do something', () => {
    var d = new Date().toString();

    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.get('http://google.com');
    const searchTextBox = browser.element(by.id('lst-ib'));

    searchTextBox.sendKeys(d);

    //expect(something).toBe(true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use momentjs

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
const today = moment().format("MMM Do YY");
```

more info here
https://momentjs.com/